# Parse-Server Quick Install on Raspberry Pi

Tags: parse-server, raspberry-pi3

I completed the install of Parse-Server on a Raspberry Pi 3 as per the [instructions](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#embedded/raspberrypi)

I updated the main.c file with a new AppID and ClientID.  Per the instructions, I built and ran the TestObject class:

```
make
./quickstart
```

Nothing seems to happen. Any ideas?

Comment: The instructions for installing on a Raspberry Pi are very different than the installation using npm.  Maybe just try this with npm as per these instructions here:https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Quick-Start

Comment: I've tried about everything I can think of to get this to work. First off, I don't see where Mongoldb is installed.  So, I installed it with npm and ran ran 'sudo mongodb-runner start'.  Then tried to do "make" and "./quickstart".  Still nothing seems to happen.